# How to get all bugs closed in 24h using Azure Queries

Tags: azure-devops

I need to create a query on Azure DevOps to get all bugs closed in a period of 24h.

For instance: I've opened a bug on 03/15/2021 and I closed on 03/16/2021. In this case, my query should show this kind of information

Is it possible on Azure DevOps Queries?

BR

Comment: Hi Mauricio, Does Shamrai's or WaitingForGuacamole's answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result.

Comment: Hi @EdwardHan-MSFT! Yes! I updated the post with the check that help me.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a query that looks for `Work Item Type` of `Bug`, `State` of `Closed`, and a `State Change Date` within the last 24 hours, like this:

[image: State Change Query]

Comment: Better to check the "ClosedDate"

Comment: To be honest, I've never seen the Closed Date differ from the State Change Date where the state remains Closed. The reason I specified State Change Date in my answer is to that, if the user wants to include multiple states down the road, they would be able to see the state, and the date on which the transition to the current state took place.

Comment: Thanks guy! With this I could get all the information and improve my dashboard. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Basically, queries can not calculate the difference between dates in work items. However, you can compare dates with static parameters as WaitingForGuacamole mentioned. Additional example with `Activated Date` and `Closed Date`:

[image]